# how to use (NOT IN) OR (IN) using pods in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have this query in pods

```
 $pod = pods( 'space' );

$where = array(
    'post_type'  => 'space',
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'space_type_link',
        'value'   => $space_type,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'space_capacity',
        'value'   => $capacity_range_array,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    )

);

$params = array(
    //'orderby' => 'date asc',
    //'limit' = > ,
    'where' => $where,
);

$pod->find($params);
return $pod;
```

and i'm trying to add one more condition to exclude some ID's from the query result like this

```
array(
        'key' => 'id',
        'value'   => 91,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
```

but is not working how can we fix this and many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As you already said, `IN` is for severall IDs.

```
'value'   => array(91, 12, 23, 4),
```

Comment: not working and i'm relay trying to use NOT IN and i try to put in the key ID,id,post_id but is not working please can you help me